# creating GamesClient object

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm tring to connect my game with Google Play Games. 
My code:

```
GamesClient mGamesClient; 
//...
mGamesClient = new GamesClient(null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, null);
            Log.i("MyLog", "connecting");
            try{
                mGamesClient.connect();
                Log.i("MyLog", Boolean.toString(mGamesClient.isConnected()));
                Log.i("MyLog", mGamesClient.getCurrentAccountName());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("MyLog", e.toString());
            }
```

But it doesn't work.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient      at
>   com.mharezlakmh.myappp.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:85)     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
>     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4936)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What is wrong?

I think I should use constuructor:

```
mGamesClient = new GamesClient(...);
```

But constructor created with documentation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not construct the GamesClient object directly. Instead, construct it using GamesClient.Builder.

```
GamesClient client = GamesClient.Builder(this, this, this).create();
```