# Initiating the Play Services GamesClient

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am having trouble creating the `GamesClient` for the new Google Play Services.  I have tried both what the poster and the one who gave the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591505/creating-gamesclient-object) with no success.  I have followed all of the docs on setting up the Play Services (more specifically the leaderboard) but I feel as if they have no section in any of their docs on where and how to set up the `GamesClient`.  Maybe I am wrong and please link me if I am.

Right now I have the below code in my `onCreate()` but with errors.

```
GamesClient mGamesClient;
mGamesClient = new GamesClient(null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, null);
mGamesClient.connect();

//Error:  "The constructor GamesClient(Context, String, String, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, String[], int, View) is not visible.
```

I also tried this code with no success:

```
GamesClient client = GamesClient.Builder(this, this, this).create();

//Error:  "The method Builder(MainMenu, MainMenu, MainMenu) is undefined for the type GamesClient."
```

Can someone provide me with help on how to instantiate this `GamesClient`?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I have edited in the error messages into my opening post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think the answer above helps you. I struggled with your problem for hours and now I got the solution. You are doing the Builder in a wrong way, you gotta create an object of it (the documentation lacks terribly..)

```
mGamesClient = new GamesClient.Builder(getBaseContext(), this, this)
             .create();         
                mGamesClient.connect();
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Your `MainMenu` class that you are passing in to the `GamesClient.Builder` constructor as "this" needs to:

- Be a `Context`
- Implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks`
- Implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

I'm guessing that the class currently fails one or more of those requirements.
For more information on the GamesClient.Builder, [check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.Builder.html).